# (memery table)MySQL master/slave replication on the same server, after restart MySQL err: 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging

Tags: mysql, mysqlbinlog, master-slave-replication

It's used for replicating a memory table, before restart, there is no err info and replication works fine.

I have tried modifying my.cnf and restarted MySQL for many times, but it doesn't work

show slave status after restart MySQL service：

```
Slave_IO_Running: No
Last_IO_Error: Got fatal error 1236 from master when reading data from binary log: 'Binary log is not open'
```

show binary logs:

```
ERROR 1381 (HY000): You are not using binary logging
```

my.cnf:

```
    [mysqld1]
datadir                         =/var/lib/mysql
socket                          =/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
max_connections                 =5000
secure_file_priv                = ''
max_heap_table_size             = 40048576000
tmp_table_size                  = 40048576000
# Disabling symbolic-links is recommended to prevent assorted security risks
symbolic-links                  =0
user                            = mysql
server-id                       = 1
log-bin                         =/var/log/mysql_master/master-bin
log-bin-index                   =/var/log/mysql_master/master-bin.index
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 0
sync_binlog                     = 0
binlog-format                   = ROW
log-error                       =/var/log/mysqld.log
pid-file                        =/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
#skip-grant-tables

[mysqld2]
server-id           = 2
port                = 3307
socket              = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld_slave.sock
pid-file            = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld_slave.pid
datadir             = /var/lib/mysql_slave
log_error           = /var/log/mysql_slave/error_slave.log
relay-log           = /var/log/mysql_slave/relay-bin
relay-log-index     = /var/log/mysql_slave/relay-bin.index
master-info-file    = /var/log/mysql_slave/master.info
relay-log-info-file = /var/log/mysql_slave/relay-log.info
read_only           = 1
max_heap_table_size     = 40048576000
tmp_table_size          = 40048576000
#skip-grant-tables
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin=/usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = multi_admin
password   = 95multi_admin@AAA
log            = /var/log/mysqld_multi.log
```

show variables like "log_bin";

```
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| log_bin       | OFF   |
+---------------+-------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't think you can setup my.cnf with two [mysqld1/2] blocks. You'll have to create two separate my.cnf files for each of the two MySQL instances.

At the moment, it doesn't look like any of the two [mysqld] blocks are being read and applied at all when you start mysql.

Have a look at https://www.howtoforge.com/one_machine_mysql_replication for more details on how to setup replication using one server.